# Commonwealth bank and MIGS Virtual Payment Client error code

Tags: php, joomla, e-commerce, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am testing MIGS Virtual Payment Client on test account , I send my dummy cart number etc and

when response comes back to me it show error code 2 "Bank Declined Transaction" which I don't

know whether is this a correct reply or not . I know correct code is 0 but is my transaction

works fine or having some error. can I go to live server or not . Can any one help me in this regard. Waiting for reply.

Comment: what model are you using? 2-Party or 3-party of combination of both?

Comment: 2-Party only , Actually I am using it in Joomla . When I log in to my account I see the order but status "error" and Respond code is "2 - Declined". Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your issue is invalid CSC or the security code found at the back of the card. Also you should use a valid Test unexpired Credit card number. Also take note that if you are still in development stage your merchant ID should have prefix "TEST". See image below for error explanation.

[image]

Try to use the following test card. their CSC is 210

[image]

Comment: But sir I am using test cart , they told me that use this master cart number and 123 CSC . I also want to confirm that whether I should go to production now because it is all on testing I can show you my site with this gateway integrated. Thanks.

Comment: did you check the expiration date? Maybe it's expired already or the card number is wrong. They should also provide you different test card type such as Visa, Mastercard, AMEX etc.

Comment: I have follow all the instructions provided by the bank and found in other forums , I am basically a developer of company and my boss insisting to find solution for this , I researched very much but couldn't find any thing . Can you provide me test card number with valid CSC . If so it will be great help for me. Thanks.

Comment: The expiration date is correct also. I checked every thing with care.

Comment: I entered this in for "ard Number 512345xxxxxxx346  "                 Card Expiry 11/13

Comment: I use these specially the first cart number you can see I have sent to you but for your satisfaction I will use the second cart number

Comment: Thanks . A lot a lot and very much . I worked the second card number I don't know what was wrong but talking it work and every thing is fine . I was basically a card error . I am very happy with you . Again thank you sir.

Comment: you're welcome. I think you can Accept the answer by clicking the Check sign to close this issue :)