# MIGS Virtual Payment Client - Transaction declined

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I am testing MIGS Virtual Payment Client on a test account. When I select payment, I am directed to the Payment Server page where I can choose between Visa and MasterCard. I have been given the following test data in the MIGS manual:

[image: Test Cards]

I use 123 as CSC value. However, the transaction always fail with

```
vpc_VerStatus=E
vpc_TxnResponseCode=2
vpc_Message=Declined  //for Visa
vpc_Message=The+card+holder+was+not+authorised.+This+is+used+in+3-D+Secure+Authentication. //for MasterCard
```

By the way, if I select MasterCard, I am prompted "Please enter your OSID or the last 5 digits of your NAB ID" and a Credit Limit. I use OSID with value 123456 and Credit Limit 10000 respectively. (These are values I entered by myself as I was not given information what to input there).

I had a look at this [Commonwealth bank and MIGS Virtual Payment Client error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496014/commonwealth-bank-and-migs-virtual-payment-client-error-code) but it does not solve my problem.

Any help why the transaction is being declined?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, there's a handful of things here you need to understand/check out.

**1. Ensure the transaction value ends in $xyz.00 or it will always decline**
MIGS behaves differently in TEST and PROD.  In TEST, MIGS uses the "cents" portion of your test transactions to determine what response code to return, NOT whether you have correctly provided the necessary data for the transaction.  These cents values are as follows:

> $ XXX.00 returns "0 Transaction approved"
>   $ XXX.10 returns "1 Transaction could not be processed"
>   $ XXX.05 returns "2 Transaction declined - contact issuing bank"
>   $ XXX.68 returns "3 No reply from Processing Host"
>   $ XXX.33 returns "4 Card has expired"
>   $ XXX.51 returns "5 Insufficient credit"

**2. Disable 3-D Secure**
It looks like you're also getting caught by 3DSECURE, also known as "Verified by Visa" and "Mastercard SecureCode".  Call your acquirer/bank and ask them to disable this in TEST and Prod.  Why?  Invariably when this goes live, your customers will see a screen they are not expecting that asks for more information and then either pick up the phone and ask you to "fix it" or (even worse) leave your store thinking it's fraud.

Because 3-D secure has such low takeup, even most bank support staff don't know about it.  Just today I had one of my clients call me about this "issue".  One of their customers had called their card issuer to enquire as to what this "Verified by Visa" screen was.  The bank (a major Australian bank) helpfully told them it was probably fraud and to not buy anything from that site.

3-D secure has such low penetration in Australia I'd suggest the only outcome of having it enabled is to reduce sales.  Don't use it.